# Use the value of a key as a key in mongodb aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am working on a project where user can upload a `*.csv*` file to enter user data, also he can choose which one is the email field (user may have used Email, email, E-mail or something else as the email field).

Previous Developer saved the data in following format.

```
[
  { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5de7d0d65223850135eac968"),
   groupName:"AGroup",
   primaryField:"EMail",
   FieldsData:[
     {EMail:"abc@gmail.com",otherField:123},
     {EMail:"def@outlook.com",otherField:345}
     ]
  },
  { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5de7d0d65223850135eac969"),
   groupName:"BGroup",
   primaryField:"userEmail",
   FieldsData:[
     {userEmail:"hij@hotmail.com",otherField:678},
     {userEmail:"kl@outlook.com",otherField:910}
     ]
  }
  ]
```

here **FieldData** is the data from *.csv* file and **primaryField** is the field user have chosen as the email field .

I have to get the **primaryField** name and get the corresponding field value from **FieldData**.

For Example: For first group i.e.. *AGroup* primaryField is **EMail** hence the mailList will contain the value of **FieldData.EMail**

Right now I have to do this in following steps:

- Get the **primaryField** of all the groups

  `db.Group.aggregate({$project:{_id:1,PrimaryKey:"$primaryField"}})`
- Loop over all the data
- Make query with each **groupId** and **primaryField**

  `db.Group.aggregate({$match:{ "_id" : ObjectId("5de7d0d65223850135eac968")}},
   {$project:{MailList:"$FieldsData.EMail"}})`

Please suggest a way to do the job in one query. Basically I need the data in following format

```
[
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5de7d0d65223850135eac968"), "MailList" : [ "abc@gmail.com", "def@outlook.com" ] }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5de7d0d65223850135eac969"), "MailList" : [ "hij@hotmail.com", "kl@outlook.com" ] }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and compare object keys dynamically you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html). You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable `element` which will hold first found `k-v`pair matching your `PrimaryField` and then return `v` part.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            MailList: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$FieldsData",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                element: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        {
                                            $filter: {
                                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$this" },
                                                cond: {
                                                    $eq: [ "$$this.k", "$primaryField" ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            in: "$$element.v"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WsF1WaZmR7L)